# Implicit generator inside brackets of constructor class?

Tags: python

```
a = (x for x in range(5))
print(type(a))  # prints "<class 'generator'>"
```

But this raises `SyntaxError` (as expected):

```
a = x for x in range(5)
```

If I want to define a tuple with values from a generator, both of these work:

```
tup1 = tuple(x for x in range(5))
tup2 = tuple((x for x in range(5)))
```

In `tup1`, the brackets are part of the constructor of the `tuple` class. But why does it work?

Comment: Because it was defined that way. And also to not clash with the `for` loop syntax

Comment: @JBernardo But what is getting passed to the constructor of the tuple class? And is the first approach correct?

Comment: The brackets have 2 functions (wrap the generator and the function call) in `tup1` example. This is the right way to do if you only have 1 argument in the function.

Comment: @JBernardo is it correct approach?

Comment: For sure it is. Both mean the same thing, though

Comment: @JBernardo But the constructor of tuple can take any iterator, in this case a generator. But the generator expression definition says a generator expression should be wrapped around two round brackets. That's what I don't understand. Because tuples are immutable and it needs an object (an iterator) to be initialized (once). So, that object should (in this case a generator) should be passed to the constructor of the tuple. So, my question is does it implicitly defines a generator? My guess would be that it is a syntactic sugar and the actual logic may be different.

Comment: As I said above. The brackets are there. They are just performing 2 jobs: The function call and to wrap the generator.

Comment: Also, try adding another argument to the function and you will see what happens

Comment: @JBernardo It says `SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument`: Ok. the genexp should be the sole argument! Got it.

Comment: @Chris_Rands No, with `tup2` the argument is still a generator:
`print(type((x for x in range(5))))  # prints "<class 'generator'>"`

Answer (score 1):

In your example:

- The first `a1 = (x for x in range(5))` is a generator
- The second `a2 = x for x in range(5)` is invalid
- The third `tup1 = tuple(x for x in range(5))`
- and fourth `tup2 = tuple((x for x in range(5)))` convert the generator to a tuple. Compare to writing `tuple(a1)`.

The third approach is preferred as it is more clear and less noisy if you want to end up with a tuple. The first approach is only a generator, which would be preferred if you don't actually need the instance itself, but e.g. want to loop over it.

Comment: There is no such thing as "tuple comprehension". This is a generator that is later converted to a tuple. Both forms are exactly the same operation

Comment: What @JBernardo said. All iterable types in Python are supposed to be able to be instantiated with a single iterable argument, which can be a generator: `set(x for x ...)`,  `tuple(x for x ...)`, etc. `[x for x ...]` is just syntactic sugar for `list(x for x ...)`.

Comment: Thanks, changed it.